# The best way to update by patch mapping object with set in fields

Tags: spring, mapping, entity, field, patch

What is the best way to do patch mapping on object like this:

```
@Data
public class UnifiedOfferEntity {
    private String companyName;
    private String city;
    private String title;
    private Set<SkillEntity> skills;
```

}

In entity I have many to many realtion. I did method for update where I send map<fieldName, value> and it works properly until I am trying to put set to the request body.

```
public UnifiedOfferEntity patchEntity(String id, Map<Object, Object> fields) {
    UnifiedOfferEntity unifiedOfferEntity = getEntityById(id);
    fields.forEach((key, value) -> {
        Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(UnifiedOfferEntity.class, (String) key);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        ReflectionUtils.setField(field, unifiedOfferEntity, value);
    });
    return unifiedOfferEntity;
}
```

I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Set field com.example.jobfinder.entity.UnifiedOfferEntity.seniority to java.util.ArrayList
```

Answer (score 0):

have you thought in this approach:

```
 public UnifiedOfferEntity patchEntity(String id, Map<Object, Object> fields) {
        UnifiedOfferEntity unifiedOfferEntity = getEntityById(id);
        enhanceUnitedOfferEntity(unifiedOfferEntity,fields);
    
        return unifiedOfferEntity;
    }
```

where the method would manually populate the objet based on keys as constants.. or another object...

```
 private void enhanceUnitedOfferEntity(UnifiedOfferEntity unifiedOfferEntity, Map<Object, Object> fields){
    fields.forEach((k, v) ->
      switch(k) {
        case "COMPANY_NAME":
          unifiedOfferEntity.setCompanyName(v);
        case "CITY":
          unifiedOfferEntity.setCity(v);
        case "TITLE":
          unifiedOfferEntity.setTitle(v);
          break;
        case "SKILLS":
          unifiedOfferEntity.setSkills(v);
          break;
        default:
      });
    }
```